Power BI Desktop - Create grouping of data with aggregate information in report table
For background, I have extensive experience with MS Reporting Services in the past, but now need to create reports via Power BI Desktop.
I have a table in PBI that is pulling data from an MSSS database ORDERS. My query to retrieve this is as follows:
SELECT
OrderID,    --varchar, custom to each row
CustomerID, --varchar, each appears in many rows
Order Desc  --varchar
Profit      --float

I have no problem creating a table with a column for each of these and one row per record, nor is there any issue sorting this table by OrderID and/or CustomerID. However, what I am trying to do is create the table in a way that groups rows by CustomerID. For each customer ID, there will be a header row with the CustomerID and sum of Profit values of all applicable rows. Under this header line, it would list all OrderIDs and OrderDescs for that customer. I would also like to alphabetize the order in which Customers are listed.
I've done this a thousand times in Reporting Services, but I'm struggling to figure out how to accomplish it in PBI. If anyone knows how, the help would be greatly appreciated.
ETA: I mocked up this example of the formatting I need to help clarify what I am looking for:


Is the table your expected output? then could you pls provide some sample data?
